# Tried to use gets with structs but it doesn't work

Tags: c

```
typedef struct local {
    char ender[81];  
    int room;         
} Local;

typedef struct man {
    Local *loc;       
} Man;    

main() {
Man *c1;
c1 = (Man *) malloc(n*sizeof(Man));
c1.loc = &c1;

for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
     printf("PLACE'S NAME:\n");
             gets(c1[i]->loc->ender);
}
}
```

Hi everyone!

I'm having problems on this C program, can anyone help me?

I need to ask to the user a name from a place. For doing that I did put printf (see above) and I used gets to put that name on c1->loc>ender, but it's not working.

Tried everything, but still now having sucess. 
Any help?

Thanks!

Here's what's apearring:
[image]

Comment: This won't even compile. Is that your problem? Then you should look at error messages.

Comment: don't ever use `gets`

Comment: What is `i` in `c1[i]`.  Post a [mcve]

Comment: Clearly state the problems you are having.  "I'm having problems" is vague.  Be descriptive "it's not working." lacks details.  How did it not work for you?

Comment: `c1` is pointer, double check the operators which can be applied to pointers. `. ` is not there.

Comment: change `c1,loc` to `c1->loc`, or al least, `(*c1).loc`. both expresion mean the same.

Comment: Pictures of code or text are less appreciated here than actual text, which can be copied, pasted, compiled, searched, ... all of which makes helping you and using your post in the future easier. Please [edit] your question to improve this.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm going to edit this man. Thanks

Comment: Jean-François said this already, but I'll say it again: please, *please* don't use `gets`.  Not even just this once. Use `fgets` instead.  (It may be a teensy bit of a nuisance to deal with the `\n`, but you'll have to learn how to do that sooner or later, and it might as well be now.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c1` is a pointer, double-check the operators which can be applied to pointers. `.` is not there.

That is what the compiler tells you here.

Using `c1->` might get you a little closer to your goal, but as mentioned in the comments, there is more weirdness going on in your code.
Using strict warnings by your compiler might help.